# Linux -what is lifetime of a shared mutex and cond variable

Tags: linux, mutex

i created a shared mutex and conditional variable on shared memory for communication between two process (producer and consumer) , if i close both application , and run again , i can lock , unlock mutex and signal conditional variable without recreate them on shared memory again , mutex and cond variable are working good without recreate them , how is this possible ? making shared a mutex and cond variable , makes them lifetime until restart machine ? Note : if i press ctrl + c and interrupt consumer and restart again both application locked and i need to delete /dev/shm/ipcfile .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether a mutex is locked or unlocked depends on the values that are stored in the memory corresponding to it.  Shared memory persists until you delete it and it is no longer used, so if you create a shared memory area with a mutex in it and lock it, it will remain locked.  If the mutex is unlocked, it will still have been initialized, since the shared memory segment persists.

If you want to consistently produce an environment where your mutex is unlocked on startup, use POSIX shared memory with `O_TRUNC` in the producer and then call `ftruncate` and `mmap` to allocate your memory, and then initialize the mutex.  The consumer (or multiple consumers) can then lock the mutex and unlock the mutex, knowing it's been created.  Since the producer truncates the memory, any old mutex state there will be destroyed.

It's also possible to do this with SysV shared memory, but a little less elegant.  You would just remove the segment to be destroyed with `shmctl` using `IPC_RMID` in the producer, ignoring any errors, and then create a new shared memory segment.  Then you can initialize the mutex in the memory area.

Comment: are mutex and cond variable  kernel objects ? , how kernel keep them alive after process terminated ,they are just like variables ? is there a relationship with process task_struct which created them ?

Comment: They are stored in memory and managed in userspace.  Locking and unlocking them can involve the kernel, but their locked or unlocked state is stored in the memory.  They remain alive because the shared memory area remains around with the mutex state.